# Enable LocalOnlyHotspot with 2.4GHz frequency only on Android 12 devices

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I created an Android app that starts a local-only hotspot by making the call StartLocalOnlyHotspot().  The problem is that when I run it on Android 12 devices, it always create a 5GHz network but my peripherals connecting to the hotspot can only do 2.4GHz.  Are there any ways that I can override and forcing the hotspot to be 2.4GHz?  I could not access much of the configurations on the underlying softAP and I tried to invoke the system APIs getSoftAPConfiguration and setSoftAPConfiguration but that did not get me anywhere.  Thanks for the help.